# Surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism

I have been trying to derive a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

What are some examples of something like this? I require an additional condition that $\phi(x,y) = (0,z)$ (where $z$ is 0 or 1) if and only if $y = -2x$.

So far I have
$\varphi(x,y) = (2x+y, y\text{ mod 2})$ which meets my condition but is not surjective, any way I can fix this?

Comment: The condition $\frac{y}{x}=-2$ is ill-defined when $x=0$; what is meant in this case?  Is your condition supposed to be $y = -2x$?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of the map you tried, first consider $g = \pmatrix{2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1}\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Since $\det g =1$, it's a surjection $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$, and clearly $g(x, y) = (0, z)$ for some $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ iff $y = -2x$.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Can you tell me how you came up with the matrix? I just want a better idea on how to solve this kind of problem in the future

Comment: The condition $y = -2x$ gives you the top row of the matrix, and then you can complete it to an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest approach to this is:

- Find *all* homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$
- Check which of them satisfy the conditions you need.

Comment: Is there an easy way to characterize all homomorphisms between these two groups?

Comment: @jackson5 - you just need to check where (1,0) and (0,1) go.. once you do this all else is determined. So it is easy to write down all homomorphisms

Comment: @jackson5: Yes, since $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a free abelian group.

Comment: Looking at it this way, it seems to suggest that such a homomorphism is not possible! I need to send $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ to generators right, and I believe that $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are generators for $Z\times Z/2Z$.But no matter which way I map these pairs, it looks like my condition cannot be met